# Access website only by HTTP except for 2 pages

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I need help with users accessing my site via HTTPS. I only want to have 2 pages able to be accessed via HTTPS. All other pages should be accessed HTTP only and if the user tries to access the page via HTTPS it will redirect them to the HTTP version of that page. I have tried several .htaccess files but I cannot seem to get any of them to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what are your page names you want to access through https?

Comment: They are: enroll.php & Registered.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of different ways:

1. You could either place some logic in the 2 pages (`enroll.php` and `Registered.php`) to redirect to HTTPS.

   ```
   if ($_SERVER['HTTPS']!=”on”)
   {
       $redirect= “https://”.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
       header(“Location:$redirect”);
   }
   ```
2. Assuming you are using Apache Web Server (other web servers including IIS are fairly similar with redirect mechanism), you can employ pattern matching and for these two URLs, specify a redirect to HTTPS.

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
   RewriteRule (enroll.php) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
   RewriteRule (Registration.php) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
   ```

Comment: I understand that and I know there is a way to do it, I just do not know how to do it.

Comment: @WebUser your rewriterules will not function properly.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey, you probably have a better handle on rewrite module.

Comment: @WebUser, this works partly for me. When a user accesses my enroll.php page, the HTTPS is valid and correct. However, it does not stop the user from accessing any of my other pages via HTTPS. Any help?

Comment: If you want to go the rewrite/.htcaccess route, refer to @ThinkingMonkey's answer above. I believe his answer is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to a `.htaccess` files and place it in the `DocumentRoot` of your directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} (?:(?:enroll|Registered)\.php)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:(?:enroll|Registered)\.php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

---

Enable logging of rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/path/to/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

Put the above 3 lines in your `virtualhost`. restart the httpd.

`RewriteLogLevel 9` Using a high value for Level will slow down your Apache server dramatically! Use the rewriting logfile at a Level greater than 2 only for debugging! 
Level 9 will log almost every rewritelog detail.

do a `find  / -name httpd.conf` or `find  / -name apache.conf` or `find  / -name apache2.conf` to find where your conf file is. Usually in: `/etc/httpd/conf`.

Where did you add the settings for SSL? 
`SSLCertificateFile` `SSLCertificateKeyFile` `SSLCertificateChainFile` etc

Comment: Thanks for the help. Okay, I just tried this rule, and it works when I try to access a page via HTTPS by redirecting the user to the HTTP version. However, when I try accessing the HTTPS page (enroll.php), it says my SSL certificate is not valid. Do you know why it would do this? thanks

Comment: Do you have a registered certificate for `HTTPS://whateveryourdomainis/`?  You have to pay hard cash for this and also register it with you hosting provider (or just pay your hosting provider to do this on your behalf).

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey Yes, I do. I have an SSL certificate and it validates when I do not use your code. However, when I use your code, it shows the red x thru the HTTPS in the url bar. Any suggestions?

Comment: @three3 Do you mean to say your site gets connected? but a red X thru the HTTPS appears in the URL bar?

Comment: @three3 Do you have access to `.conf` files of Apache.

Comment: I should because I have access to my root directory. I am not sure where that file is located. I cannot seem to find it. Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: Most likely, your server doesn't correctly know its own name, so it's redirecting a person to another name that's not the common name in the certificate. Replace `%{HTTP_HOST}` (in the middle block) with the common name in the certificate.